# How to change the fluxbox keyboard configuration?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, wireless-keyboard, fluxbox

I am now using Ubuntu with it's native window manager, but I want to use fluxbox, because of the performance and because I used it before and I liked it... But, for some reason, fluxbox on this new computer of mine changes the keyboard layout! I want it to be Croatian. Also, on the login screen the keyboard layout is also different, only when I login to Ubuntu or Ubuntu 2D I actually get my keyboard, and it's a bit frustrating!

Comment: fluxbox usually does not change the keyboard layout, external programs do. do you start such programs?

Comment: I've set Gedit and the terminal to run on the startup, I doubt that they induce such changes. Should I try to start it without them?

Comment: if you mean `.fluxbox/startup` then yes, try without them. you could also add something like `setxkbmap croat` in `.fluxbox/startup`.

Comment: No, it is still the same...

Comment: and when you execute `setxkbmap croat` after fluxbox is done? which version of fluxbox?

Comment: It works now! But, there is no sound: http://askubuntu.com/questions/134327/there-is-no-sound-in-fluxbox...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have installed a new version of Ubuntu, and all keyboard problems are now solved!